# Node.js document initilize

Tags: node.js, dom

What is the right way to initilize DOM API document in Node.js? I have an html file with head and body and I need to intilize document with this file? I know that there is a method documentElement but it is said that it is read-only.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? NodeJS is server side javascript and does not need to work with HTML.

Comment: I want to write a test with jest and testing library to my frontend app.